# Users denied access to certain site collection until an administrator opens it

Tags: 2007, security, access-denied

We are having a problem with users getting "Access denied" errors when trying to access a certain site collection.  These users all have the proper permissions to the site and have accessed it in the past.  If one of the site collection administrators opens the site themselves though, the users can then access the site without any problems for the rest of the day.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are there custom web parts or external data on the site?

Comment: Just a calendar.

Comment: Are you using custom master page for this site collection?